# there has been a growing recognition

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

The context:

> The classical definition of project success centers on achieving results on time, on budget, and producing the agreed deliverables: the triple constraints of time, cost, and scope. Yet, over the past decade there has been **a growing recognition** that creating the requested deliverables does not ensure “success.”

Are the phrases **a growing recognition**, **there has been a growing recognition** common, idiomatic?

Comment: It's worth putting such phrases into Google's Ngram Viewer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+growing+recognition&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20growing%20recognition%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

Um, no. An Idiom is a phrase that has a metaphorical (not literal) meaning (for example “Break a leg” … actually means “Good luck”).

"A growing recognition" itself is not an idiom an simply means that there is an ever increasing (growing) acknowledgement of the existence, validity, or legality of something (recognition).

Comment: Yeah, it's just a phrase. It's fairly common, but like @Ronald Sole says, check something like the Ngram viewer if you want an idea of its usage.

Answer (score 0):

*a growing recognition* is an idiomatic expression, which means acceptance/agreement/acknowledgment that is growing/increasing/expanding.

Similarly, you can say *growing concern/controversy/success/popularity*.